# SCM8014 to FVS338

Tags: networking, router, static-ip, netgear

I have a SMC8014 Router/Modem that Comcast provided me with their business class service.  It was not filtering malicious traffic as aggressively as I had hoped, so I purchased a NetGear ProSafe FVS338, and put this behind the SMC8014, and all my machines behind that.  After some brief configuration, all machines can see out to the internet.

I also have a single web server, and I have not been able to configure things so that incoming requests can reach it.  This is where I need help!

I would like to have the FVS339 do NAT, so that I can assign a 192.168 address to my webserver.  I've tried everything I know of, and I can't get things going.

I set the SMC8014 to have a LAN facing IP of 10.0.0.1, and I assigned the FVS339 a WAN facing IP of 10.0.0.2.  I would like to be able to tell the SMC8014 to just forward all traffic to 10.0.0.2, but I haven't had any success.

In my (unfortunately limited) understanding, what I probably want here is a static route, but I don't know how to cofigure one, or if this is really what I want.  The SMC8014 wants a Destination IP, a Subnet Mask and a Gateway IP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First some advice: use one router or the other, not both (at least until you understand this better).

For outgoing connections, the router does DNAT = Dynamic Network Address Translation, where several internal IP addresses appear to be connecting from your external address.  For incoming connections to your webserver the router does SNAT = Static NAT, forwarding the incoming connections to the internal IP address. You should be able to find config options for SNAT.